# How to use datahook to get an element through selenium (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have the HTML code as:
`<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R252N8IFRXV8TW/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B071NZZHF9">Security concern</a>`

and i have to search the element by data-hook as the class name is common for other attributes also and href and link-text are dynamic as it is changing for the next element as there are multiple elements that i need to fetch.

Can i search it by data-hook. If yes could someone help me with it!

Comment: try with `web_hook = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-hook="review-title"]')
print(web_hook.text)`

Comment: thanks @simpleApp, the a reffers to the tag ? I mean, if I had <span data-hook = "  ".....in the find_element argument it would be driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-hook="   "]') ?

Comment: yes, you got it! `a` is a tag, so your span code will work too.